# Spring Boot/React admin login

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, security

I try create admin side for me application, whit login form. Use Spring starter-security for backend. But when try enter me username and password in react login form get error.

ERROR

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/admin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Login.js:9

GET http://localhost:8080/admin net::ERR_FAILED

Me Security Configuration:

```
package com.example.test.Configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration{


    @Value("${spring.security.user.name}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.security.user.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username(username)
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode(password))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
                                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Me Admin Controller:

```
package com.example.test.Controller;

import com.example.test.Entity.Airport;
import com.example.test.Services.AirportIntefaceService;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class AdminController {
    private final AirportIntefaceService airportService;

    public AdminController(AirportIntefaceService airportService) {
        this.airportService = airportService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/admin/flightList")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Airport>> getAllAirport() {
        List<Airport> authors = airportService.getAllAirport();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authors);
    }
}
```

And me react Login:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/admin', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${username}:${password}`)}`
        }
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("You are loged");
      } else {
       
        console.error('Login failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Username"
        value={username}
        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```